# 3 Questions Jquery readmore plugin confused me

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i see in other example jquery code like below, Why he make variable like this

**var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj);**
why not
**var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link');**

and i got confuse what a  minTrail do in defaults object??

and onother confused in this example below what he means, Why body.length - 1 do??

**var str2 = body.substring(splitLocation, body.length - 1);**

las thing when we want to use indexof in proper condition...??

### full example of code:

```
(function($){  
 $.fn.truncate = function(options) {  

  var defaults = {  
   length: 300,  
   **minTrail: 20,**  
   moreText: "more",  
   lessText: "less",  
   ellipsisText: "..."  
  };  

  var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

  return this.each(function() {  
   obj = $(this);  
   var body = obj.html();  

   if(body.length > options.length + **options.minTrail**) {  
    var splitLocation = body.indexOf(' ', options.length);  
    if(splitLocation != -1) {  
     // truncate tip  
     var splitLocation = body.indexOf(' ', options.length);  
     var str1 = body.substring(0, splitLocation);  
     **var str2 = body.substring(splitLocation, body.length - 1);**  
     obj.html(str1 + '<span class="truncate_ellipsis">' + options.ellipsisText +   
      '</span>' + '<span  class="truncate_more">' + str2 + '</span>');  
     obj.find('.truncate_more').css("display", "none");  

     // insert more link  
     obj.append(  
      '<div class="clearboth">' +  
       '<a href="#" class="truncate_more_link">' +  options.moreText + '</a>' +   
      '</div>'  
     );  

     // set onclick event for more/less link  
     **var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj);**  
     **var moreContent = $('.truncate_more', obj);**  
     **var ellipsis = $('.truncate_ellipsis', obj);**  
     moreLink.click(function() {  
      if(moreLink.text() == options.moreText) {  
       moreContent.show('normal');  
       moreLink.text(options.lessText);  
       ellipsis.css("display", "none");  
      } else {  
       moreContent.hide('normal');  
       moreLink.text(options.moreText);  
       ellipsis.css("display", "inline");  
      }  
      return false;  
       });  
    }  
   } // end if  

  });  
 };  
})(jQuery);
```

***Thank's Hopefully Your answer!!***

Answer (score 2):

First thing

> var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj);
>
> why not var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link');

obj is the context.. which `obj = $(this);`  So it will only get descendant elements with class=truncate_more_link

jQuery you can pass in a context and it works the same as using find.. so the equivalent to

```
$('.truncate_more_link', obj);
```

would be

```
$(obj).find('.truncate_more_link');
```

Second thing

> Why body.length - 1 do??
>
> var str2 = body.substring(splitLocation, body.length - 1);

`var body = obj.html();` meaning it gets all the contents inside current element.. `body.length - 1` equals last character in the contents.. since it's 0 indexed - so substring starts at `splitlocation` index all the way until the end

Answer (score 1):

.truncate_more is a class so there may be more then 1 elements having this same class.

now if you notice the following is returning the value which is returned by the anonymous function.

```
  return this.each(function() {  
   obj = $(this);  
   .....................
   ...........................
   ..................................
   });
```

the above will be executed for each element having class name .truncate_more

so this statement lopps(iterates through all the elements having the class as .truncate_more.

so this `var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj);` will assign elements one by one to the `var morelink` and will eventually set the click handlers for them.

and about your second confusion

```
var str2 = body.substring(splitLocation, body.length - 1);
```

since body is an array and 0 indexed so for accessing the first character in body this statement is used.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at first..

```
var moreLink = $('.truncate_more_link', obj)
```

it selected the specific class truncate_more_link with context obj has own parent.

second..

```
var str2 = body.substring(splitLocation, body.length - 1);

     find the substring on splitlocation in context  with length the body minus 1;
```